# How to build input field with react text area autocomplete feature and having bracket pair colorizer in the same input using javascript?

Tags: javascript, prismjs

To add trigger for auto suggestion like @ and # as well as the matching brackets will be highlighted using same colour, please guide me to build such input field using javascript so that it can be used in react application

[text](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@webscopeio/react-textarea-autocomplete)
I used this to have input for auto complete using triggers but it doesn't support matching bracket highlighter.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.